# Fetching images from dropbox and showing them in android gridview

Tags: android, api, dropbox

I would like to fetch images from dropbox and show them inside my android application gridview.

The first problem is images should be inside drawable folder in order to show in gridview.
The second problem is how to download or fetch images from dropbox folder. Dropbox Sync API only show data inside my dropbox and it's on server not on my client app.

Could someone please help me with these difficulties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So let's get this straight; you want the images to display in gridview in your app, but Dropbox Sync API takes you to your Dropbox folder? It'd also be helpful if you showed your code.

Comment: it lists out all the files inside my dropbox folder. But all these files are stored on dropbox server not inside local storage. i'm having difficulty to download those images into my app.

Answer (score 1):

here is the way i have achieved

```
    public void getMediaList(String MEDIA_PATH) {
    Logger.e(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
        try {
            Entry dirent = mApi.metadata(MEDIA_PATH, 0, null, true, null);
            for (Entry ent: dirent.contents) {
                System.out.println("/"+ent.path);
                if (ent.isDir) {//ent.path
                    scanDirectory(ent);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(ent);
                }
            }
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getFile();
    }
}


ArrayList<String> List_dropBox_images = new ArrayList<String>();
private void getFile()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        try {
            System.gc();
            DropboxLink shareLink = mApi.share(list.get(i).get("Path"));    
            Logger.e("",""+shareLink.url);
            String shareAddress = getLocation(shareLink.url);
            if(shareAddress==null) continue;
            String shareAddress_f= shareAddress.replaceFirst("https://www.dropbox.com/", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/");
            Logger.e(""," address "+shareAddress_f);
            List_dropBox_images.add(shareAddress_f);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.gc();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 


}


private String getLocation(String link)  {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL(link);
        final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        return urlConnection.getHeaderField("location");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return link;
}
```

ALL of your solution

Try it, Enjoy coding..